# How can i pass arrays between HTML pages by using ONLY HTML and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I have this simple code in the test0.html file, it sends data to test1.html :

```
<body>
    <form action="test1.html">
        <input type="text" name="array[0]" placeholder="val1" id="">
        <input type="text" name="array[1]" placeholder="val2" id="">
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>

</body>
```

Then i have this code on the test1.html, that is supposed to send some new data back to test0:

```
<body>
<form action="test0.html">
    <input type="text" name="array[2]" placeholder="val3" id="">
    <input type="text" name="array[3]" placeholder="val4" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="send back">
</form>
```

When i send data back to test0, i just get the newest data typed in test1.html. I'd like to know how to keep track of the ones sent previously from test0.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `localStorage` to keep track of data

Comment: Okay that makes more sense...

Answer (score 1):

As the default form method is GET, the form parameters will be passed using the query parameters

So you can add a hidden input field to your form for each query parameters.

```
<body>
  <form action="test0.html">
    <input type="text" name="array[2]" placeholder="val3">
    <input type="text" name="array[3]" placeholder="val4">
    <input type="submit" value="send back">
  </form>

  <script>
    (function() {
      var form = document.querySelector("form");
      var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    
      for (var key of params.keys()) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "hidden";
        input.name = key;
        input.value = queryParams.get(key);
        form.insertBefore(input, form.firstChild);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You take the sent data and store it temporarily, so you can then pass it on to the following pages. Input fields of type hidden are suitable here.

```
<form action="test0.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="array[0]" value="SUBMITTED_DATA">
  <input type="hidden" name="array[1]" value="SUBMITTED_DATA">
  <input type="text" name="array[2]" placeholder="val3" id="">
  <input type="text" name="array[3]" placeholder="val4" id="">

   <input type="submit" value="send back">
</form>
```

With this approach, you can not determine whether the data were subsequently edited! Here a signature can provide remedy.